# "No add-ins currently available." when deploying add-in using Centralized Deployment

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I am trying to deploy an add-in with add-in commands on the desktop version of office 365, using the Centralized Deployment method.

I followed the instructions for Centralized Deployment and the addin appears as "on" in the Office 365 admin center. I used both "Everyone" and "Specific User/Group", but when I open the Word application and go to Add-ins, under "Admin Managed" I see no addins , and the message `"No add-ins currently available."` The addin is'nt visible neither on Word 2016 Desktop (with subscription) nor Word Online. I have also tried deploying addins from office store using the same method (Centralized Deployment) but they also don't show up.

I have Word version 1708 (8431.2270), and I am using a developer subscription.

Do you have any suggestions to fix it or know why it is not working? Thank you.

Also,
I noticed that I am getting a 403 Error when refreshing the Admin Managed tab (when calling `https://euc-word-edit.officeapps.live.com/we/AddinServiceHandler.ashx`)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you authenticating in Word using an account from the same tenant you deployed this in? In other words, if your copy of Word 2016 for Windows is authenticated with your work/school credentials then the add-in wouldn't show up.

Comment: I am authenticated on word 2016 for windows with the same account with which I deployed.

Comment: I managed somehow (probably by enabling exchange) to deploy the addins from office store(using Centralized deployment), but still my addin is not visible

Comment: I checked with fiddler and the response from /ews/exchange.asmx contains all addins including my addin, but it does not show up in Admin Managed Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, by enabling Exchange, and my manifest had an issue.
I changed `<CustomTab id="HelloWorld" x:type="CustomTab">` to `<CustomTab id="HelloWorld">` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So I recently Identified this issue. This is because you have unchecked one settings. So getting that settings checked will let show addon. You can see the picture below.

[image: Image 1]

Go to the account settings then click on Manage settings in the Account Privacy

[image: Image 2]

Then Check "Turn on optional connected experiences", then Restart the Ms Word and you are good to go