# Admin Managed Excel Add-in not visible in Office365 Excel

Tags: excel, office-js, word-web-addins

We have a Excel Web Addin, that was deployed to a group of users using the Office 365 Admin Center. But the add-in is not visible in Excel 2016 (Version 1803,Build 9126.2275, Click to Deploy) for those users.

Fiddler trace shows the following when the user tries to refresh the "Admin Managed" add-in dialog box.
[image]

Fiddler Trace

```
<MessageText>User must have a mailbox for name resolution operations.</MessageText>
<ResponseCode>ErrorNameResolutionNoMailbox</ResponseCode>
```

I also came across this post
["No add-ins currently available." when deploying add-in using Centralized Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160709/no-add-ins-currently-available-when-deploying-add-in-using-centralized-deploy)

that talks about enabling Exchange.  I am not sure what that really means.

So any help is appreciated in understanding the issue and resolution.

Thanks
-kudlur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, I'd assume you're having issues with users not being assigned mailboxes, which are required to enable Centralized Deployed add-ins.

Could you try running through the compatibility checking steps outlines here? It will help provide more detail on the exact issue.

Download the compatibility checker here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55270

Run the compatibility checker Start an elevated PowerShell.exe window.

Run the \Import-Module O365CompatibilityChecker\ command.

Run the \Invoke-CompatibilityCheck\ command, which prompts you for TenantDomain (for example, TailspinToysIncorporated.onmicrosoft.com) and TenantAdmin credentials, and then requests consent.

You can also find more ways to debug in this help article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ie/office365/admin/manage/centralized-deployment-of-add-ins?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fDetermine-if-Centralized-Deployment-of-add-ins-works-for-your-Office-365-organization-b4527d49-4073-4b43-8274-31b7a3166f92&view=o365-worldwide#BKMK_UserAndGroupAssignments?omkt=de-CH&ui=de-DE&rs=de-CH&ad=CH

Thanks, Alan

Comment: Thank You Alan. Users not being assigned exchange mailboxes was the reason for the add-in not showing up. Once my mailbox was assigned, I was able to see the add-in under"Admin Managed" section. I also had to add the following metatag to make sure IE was forced to load the add-in in edge mode, as my add-in is a angular 7 app  <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">